# Swift String to Date conversion from youtube API publishedAt

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert this date string to a date object. This is the format that youtube API sends for a published at date.

> 2022-10-26T02:40:04.645878Z

```
let all_time_date = "2022-10-26T02:40:04.645878Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let allTimeDate = dateFormatter.date(from: all_time_date)
```

I get a null value on conversion and do not know if its the .dateFormat that is incorrect

Comment: You forgot the milliseconds, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ" or just "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" since only 3 decimal digits are included when parsing

Comment: That would be the problem. Thank you for your help.